# Yet another zip duplicate entry

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I've use **Kryo libs** and it's pretty good. However, when I want to create a signed APK, it keeps failing to build because of the error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\AndroidProjects\App\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\AndroidProjects\App\app\importLibs\minlog-1.3.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [minlog-1.3.0.jar:com/esotericsoftware/minlog/Log$Logger.class]))

```
build gradle (module app)

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile files('importLibs/kryo-2.23.0.jar')
    compile files('importLibs/minlog-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('importLibs/objenesis-2.1.jar')
    compile files('importLibs/reflectasm-1.10.1-shaded.jar')
}
```

proguard file

```
     proguard-rules.pro
    -dontwarn com.esotericsoftware.**
    -dontwarn org.objenesis.**
    -keep class com.esotericsoftware.**{*;}
```

What exactly do I need to write to make it work?

Comment: check `importLibs` . comment `compile files('importLibs/minlog-1.3.0.jar')` and make sure set `multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: Commenting out `minlog-1.3.0.jar` only makes `reflectasm-1.10.1-shaded.jar` have the same problem. Commenting both out makes the application unable to function.

Answer (score 1):

There can be case where a library is part of another library that you have imported in your project
Check the lib dependency tree using following command
For Android, use this line

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

or if you have a gradle wrapper:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Or else there is a less popular Android studio plugin called GradleView that can give you entire lib tree used in your application and also where it might be clashing with some other library.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and I solved it with just including `retrofit`:
['com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'](https://www.versioneye.com/java/com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit/1.9.0)

I hope it will help you too.